# Indicator function integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Let $A, B\in\mathcal A$. Assume that $\mathbb P(A) = 0.5$, $\mathbb P(B) = 0.4$ and $\mathbb P(A\cap B) = 0.1$.

Find the integral over $\Omega$ of $|2\chi_A −3\chi_B + 1|dP$.

Here, for any set $C\in\mathcal A$, $\chi_C$ denotes the indicator function of $C$.

Comment: Do you know how the Lebesgue integral of an indicator function is defined, about the linearity of the Lebesgue integral, or even how the indicator function itself is defined? If so then this exercise should be trivial. If not, read up the definitions (for example on Rudin)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $f=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{A_i}$ where the $c_i\in\mathbb R$ denote constants and the $A_i$ measurable sets then: $$\int fdP=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iP(A_i)$$
(linearity of expectation)

So wonder what values are taken by the described function, and on what sets.